# pandas fill N.A. for specific column

Tags: python, pandas, fill, na, imputation

I want to fill N.A. values in a specific column if a condition is met in another column to only replace this single class of N.A. values with an imputed / replacement value.

E.g.  I want to perform: `if column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = N.A fillna_in_column2 with value 'replacementvalue'`

How do I achieve this in pandas?

Trying to do this via `dataframe[dataframe['firstColumn'] == 'value1'].fillna({'column2':'replacementValue'}` does not work as the length of the overall records is modified. So far I could not get an inplace modification to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.loc[(df['col1']==val1) & (df['col2'].isnull()), 'col2'] = replacement_value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
cond1 = df['column1'] == value1
cond2 = np.isnan(df['column2'])

df['column2'][cond1 & cond2] = replacement_value
```